# Kusto Query get total number of unique CVEs

Tags: kql

I'm trying to create a Kusto Query to get the total number of unique CVEs viewed by Defender.

I think that is the information that is shown on the "Weaknesses" dashboard, but I would like to extract that in a query, but I'm new to Kusto Query and I'm not understanding how can I do that. Can anyone help me on how to build this query?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide sample data + required result in CSV format.

Comment: Hi, I was able to build up the query, which is this:
DeviceTvmSoftwareVulnerabilities 
    | distinct CveId 
    | count